Issue for applying penalty method to find the minimum distance between point $y$ and $a^Tx=b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$
According to Approach0, this question is new.
I am practicing problems, no solutions, for my optimization course (not homework, just extra practices).
Problem:

Apply penalty method to find the minimum distance between point $y$ and $a^Tx=b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

My attempt:
Penalty function $$\phi(x,c)=\|x-y\|^2+c(a^Tx-b)^2$$Thus$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}=2x-2y+2c(a^Tx-b)a=2x-2y+2c(aa^T)x-2(cb)a$$So by setting it equals to $0$, we get $$\begin{align} 
(I+c(aa^T))x&=y+(cb)a\\
\implies x&=(I+c(aa^T))^{-1}(y+(cb)a)\\
&=(\frac{1}{c}I+aa^T)^{-1}(\frac{y}{c}+b\times a)\\
&\to b(aa^T)^{-1}a\tag{As $c\to\infty$}\quad\quad(1)
\end{align}$$
However the optimal solution is $b(aa^T)^{-1}a$ from my calculation, but it has no relation with point $y$. And I am not sure if $(1)$ is correct. Thanks!

Are you sure you correctly took the derivative of $||x-y||^2 = (x^T-y^T)(x-y)$?

I think I got it correct, from here, replace $x$ by $x-y$, then it is $2(x-y)$

Isn't the answer $\frac {a^Ty - b}{|a|}$?

@user317176 I am not sure if it is correct, because I don't have solutions. Could you please explain more about it?

It is the generalization of the distance formula from Algebra II.

@user317176 Ah yes, I nearly forgot it. However I want to solve it using penalty method.

@YvesDaoust Why? $(a^Tx)a=\begin{pmatrix}a_1(a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n)\\vdots\ a_n(a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1^2x_1+\cdots+a_na_1x_n\\vdots\ a_na_1x_1+\cdots+a_n^2x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1^2&\cdots&a_na_1\\vdots&&\vdots\ a_na_1&\cdots&a_n^2\end{pmatrix}x=(aa^T)x$. Here is the details.

The issue is that it is not true to say
$$\left(\frac{1}{c}I + aa^\top\right)^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{c}y + ba\right) \to b(aa^\top)^{-1}a, \quad \mathrm{as}\,\, c \to \infty,$$
since $aa^\top$ is not invertible when $n\ge 2$. For example, set
$$a = \begin{pmatrix}
 -1\\
 3
\end{pmatrix}, \quad y = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}, \quad b = 4.
$$
We have
$$\left(\frac{1}{c}I + aa^\top\right)^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{c}y + ba\right) 
= \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{11c+1}{10c+1}\\[4pt]
 \frac{17c+2}{10c+1}
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{11}{10}\\[4pt]
\frac{17}{10}
\end{pmatrix}$$
which is the desired result.
The right way to take limit is given as follows. We have
\begin{align*}
 x &= (I + c aa^\top)^{-1}(y + cba)\\
 &= \left(I - \frac{caa^\top}{1 + ca^\top a }\right)(y + cba)\\
 &= y + cba -  \frac{ca^\top y}{1 + ca^\top a }a -  \frac{c^2ba^\top a}{1 + ca^\top a } a\\
 &= y + \frac{cb}{1 + ca^\top a }a - \frac{ca^\top y}{1 + ca^\top a }a \\
 &
 \to y + \frac{b}{a^\top a}a - \frac{a^\top y}{a^\top a}a,
 \quad \mathrm{as}\,\, c \to \infty.
\end{align*}
By the way, we can obtain the solution $x(c)$ without calculus. We have
$$\phi(x,c) = x^\top x + y^\top y - 2y^\top x + cx^\top aa^\top x + cb^2 - 2cb a^\top x$$
$$= x^\top(I + caa^\top)x - 2(y + cba)^T x
+ y^\top y + cb^2$$
$$=  (x - x_0)^\top (I + caa^\top)(x - x_0) - x_0^\top (I + caa^\top) x_0 + y^\top y + cb^2$$
$$\ge - x_0^\top (I + caa^\top) x_0 + y^\top y + cb^2$$
where $x_0 = (I + caa^\top)^{-1} (y + cba)$.

Your calculation is correct, but the behavior you're observing is expected due to the nature of the penalty method as $c \to \infty$, you give more importance to the second term.
I suggest you use the Largrangian penalization for minimizing the distance between $y$ and the hyperplane $a^T x = b$:
$$
\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = \|x - y\|^2 + \lambda (a^T x - b)
$$
The first-order conditions are:

$\nabla_x \mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = 2(x - y) + \lambda a = 0$, so: $x = y - \frac{\lambda}{2} a$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} = a^T x - b = 0$, so: $\lambda = \frac{2(a^T y - b)}{a^T a}$


Substitute $\lambda$ into $x$:
$$
x^* = y - \frac{(a^T y - b)}{a^T a} a
$$
This is the optimal solution. Note that using the Lagrangian method, the first order conditions are easier to compute.
